# Understanding special Scala syntax

Tags: scala

I can understand this:

```
List("one word", "another word") unzip (_ span (_ != ' '))
```

But don't get what's happening here **below** in the `span`. `span` takes a predicate and I think the braces can be omitted as `span` is used inline and has only one parameter but why isn't there any `_` and what is `' '.!=`

```
List("one word", "another word") unzip (_ span ' '.!=)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala, operators are just special-named methods. Here `' '.!=` fetches but does not apply the `!=` to the `' '` object. This method takes one parameter and returns a boolean value.

For any function `f` that takes a single argument, `(x => f(x))` and `f` are equivalent expressions – so there is no need to wrap such a function into another lambda.

The `span` method takes a predicate, and partitions a sequence (here: String) into a prefix that satisfies the predicate, and a suffix that doesn't. Here we want to get the string up to the first space.

- In the first line, we use the predicate `(_ != ' ')`, more clearly `(c => c != ' ')`.
- We can now swap the arguments of the inequality “operator”, as this operation should be reflexive. We now have: `(c => ' ' != c)`.
- We can now use the explicit method call syntax: `(c => ' '.!=(c))`.
- Next, we save that method in another variable:

  ```
  val f: (Char => Boolean) = ' '.!=
  ...
  (c => f(c))
  ```
- As stated above, `f` and `(c => f(c))` are equivalent, therefore `(_ != ' ')` and `' '.!=` must be equivalent too.